# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat

App made by someone else which I am testing, and learning from crashes and on logcat such error appears. Could you tell me what does it mean, and what am I supposed to do? I think there is something with package name. But when I checked package name of SquareImageView it showed my package: com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating but not that displayed in logcat as a package name for this class(tabian.com.instagramclone2)

```
 31.863 4690-4690/com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
    10-09 15:56:31.883 4690-4690/com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    10-09 15:56:31.893 4690-4690/com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating, PID: 4690
         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class tabian.com.instagramclone2.Utils.SquareImageView
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
             at com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.GridImageAdapter.getView(GridImageAdapter.java:55)
             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
             at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1069)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:900)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1658)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:786)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1841)
             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
            at a
    10-09 15:56:31.903 1574-3988/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating/.Share.ShareActivity
    10-09 15:56:31.913 1574-3988/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
    10-09 15:56:31.913 1574-3988/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating/.Profile.ProfileActivity
    10-09 15:56:31.913 1574-3988/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
```

Comment: In the 6th line of your xml file there is a view with an invalid property...Please post the view

Comment: You can change `<SquareImageView ... />` tag to `<tabian.com.instagramclone2.Utils.SquareImageView ... />`.

Comment: Mr. Rajab what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Android Runtime couldn't find `tabian.com.instagramclone2.Utils.SquareImageView` in your view. You are pointing to wrong class. Provide a proper package name for SquareImageView.

You, probably, customized SquareImageView into your own class. And, later forgot to change it in xml to your own customized SquareImageView.

Where is `SquareImageView`?

Comment: Which xml file?

Comment: In Android Studio > right click on project > choose Find in Path > enter text 'SquareImageView' > tap on Preview tab. Check all the xml files listed here.

Comment: Mark this answer as Accepted? and upvote? please, its my food right now

Answer (score 0):

It means that the class you used in your XML file is not present in your project that's why while inflating the layout in the class it is throwing the error ,you need to provide it with the class

Answer (score 0):

Go to your layout_view_post.xml and there remake the SquareImageView widget.  Most likely the error is because your project name is different i.e not the same as tabian.com.instagramclone2 and you have copied and pasted the code from github.  So before "Utils.SquareImageView" replace "tabian.com.instagramclone2" with your own package/project name or else the remake the widget.